# shutil copyfile invalid argument but file does exist

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to copy a file from one Sharepoint folder to another Sharepoint folder. I have the Sharepoint folder mapped to Z drive. To confirm the path is correct and file does exist, I ran the following code and received `True` as output.

```
print(os.path.isfile('Z:/abc/def.csv'))
```

Then I executed the `shutil` command to copy file

`shutil.copyfile('Z:/abc/def.csv', 'Z:/def.csv')`

and received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john\OneDrive - company\automation.py", line 92, in <module>
    ipam()
  File "C:\Users\john\OneDrive - company\automation.py", line 83, in 
    shutil.copyfile('Z:/abc/def.csv', 'Z:/def.csv')
  File "C:\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Z:/abc/def.csv'
```

Does anyone know why this error arises? I think it's possibly because I am not moving files across local drives but sharepoint folders, wondering how to resolve the issue.

P.S. I also have the Sharepoint folder added to my C drive as shortcut. If I use the C drive path (`C:/Users/john/OneDrive - company/Documents/abc/def.csv`) instead of Z drive path  (`Z:/abc/def.csv`), the shutil command works fine, without error.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace, not just the exception, so we know which specific thing `copyfile()` was doing that triggered the problem. If it was, say, trying to preserve file permissions or timestamp, or otherwise performing an operation that the filesystem in question doesn't offer, that would be useful details to know.

Comment: Do you have write permission to the `Z:/` folder?

Comment: @Barmar, ...note that "invalid argument" is on the source, not the destination, so I don't think we're looking at a write-permissions issue; at least, not on its own.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Maybe, it could be a problem with the way it reports the error.

Comment: Generally speaking, OSError is going to be thrown by a specific lower-level call, so it'll be coming from something more specific -- an `os.stat()`, an `open()`, etc -- rather than from shutil itself; so I trust the error to accurately reflect which file that lower-level operation was on. To know _which_ operation it was, though... well, we really need to see the stack trace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just added the complete traceback, thank you!

Comment: @Barmar Yes I have write access.

Comment: Okay, so this is an `open()` problem, not a `shutil` problem; that's interesting.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Gotcha, so before this line of script, I just created the def.csv file in the Z:/abc/ folder, which means I should have access to open it...

Comment: Are you able to copy the file by hand in a terminal window?

Comment: "Gotcha, so before this line of script, I just created the def.csv file in the Z:/abc/ folder" - maybe you already have it open and forgot to close it? That could cause problems on some setups, and I don't know how it would interact with Sharepoint.

Comment: _not_ -- other operating systems generally won't care, but Windows considers any write handle to serve as a lock.